# Freezing columns in a .Net Framework v4.5 GridView using.Frozen property

Tags: .net, gridview, frozen-columns

I'm trying to programmatically freeze columns in an ASP.Net GridView control with Visual Basic.

My code is taken from the msdn knowledge base at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e9w2e1(v=vs.90).aspx

The code is:

```
mydatagridview.columns("manufacturer").frozen = true
```

The GridView has been bound with data and the columns are automatically generated, the relevant one from a data field "manufacturer".

However, I get the error message:

> 'Frozen' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to correct this?

The .Frozen property is only available from .Net Framework v4.5 onwards.  When I get the compile error the page says that the .Net Framework 4.0 is being used, though I believe that this happens even when 4.5 is actually running on the server (which is how the application pool is set up in IIS).

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question here - the datagridview is a windows form control, not a GridView. Doh! Too much late night coding.